# Pymongo connection to DocumentDB cluster

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I'm facing some problems in order to programatically connect python to our AWS DocumentDB (AWS version of MongoDB) instance in a local environment. We tried the following steps:

1. To start our experiment we used the recommended AWS tutorial to create the python connection: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html.
2. Since we want to initially set this locally, we do an SSH connection to our cluster using the following command:
   ssh -i "example.pem" -L 27019:docdb.cluster-XXXXXXX.region.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 ec2-user@ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.region.compute.amazonaws.com -N -v
   This command works fine and we are able to create the tunnel and connect local port 27019 to our cluster. One important note regarding this, is that in order to reach the cluster we have to activate a VPN network.
3. We adapted our code to connect to our local port:

```
    from pymongo import MongoClient,ReadPreference
    import urllib
    import ssl
    
    username=urllib.parse.quote_plus("username")
    password=urllib.parse.quote_plus("password")
    port=27019
    host="localhost"
    dbName="general"
    
    
    dbUri = f'mongodb://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=./rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&retryWrites=false'
    print(dbUri)
    
    client = MongoClient(dbUri)
    print(client.list_database_names())
```

Running the above example we get as error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: hostname '127.0.0.1' doesn't match either of 'docdb.XXXXXXX.region.docdb.amazonaws.com', 'docdb.cluster-XXXXXXX.region.docdb.amazonaws.com', 'docdb.cluster-ro-XXXXXXX.region.docdb.amazonaws.com', Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61e7f8c811a815088e97e5a7, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('127.0.0.1', 27019) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=CertificateError("hostname '127.0.0.1' doesn't match either of 'docdb.XXXXXXX.region.docdb.amazonaws.com', 'docdb.cluster-XXXXXXX.region.docdb.amazonaws.com', 'docdb.cluster-ro-XXXXXXX.region.docdb.amazonaws.com'",)>]>
2022-01-19 11:41:27,120| ERROR   | Could not establish connection from local ('127.0.0.1', 27019) to remote ('ai-docdb-dev.cluster-cq8mixmxuhvt.eu-west-1.docdb.amazonaws.com', 27017) side of the tunnel: open new channel error:
```

This indicates 2 things: First our code is correctly using the .pem certificate and is able to get our cluster names. Second, the code is not able to understand that localhost is an address and inspect the local port 27019 for reaching the cluster.

To try to overcome this issue we also tried to substitute our code variable host to 127.0.01, however the result was the same. We also tried to tweak several parameter of the pymongo function MongoClient https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient , but the result remained the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of non-successful attempts we finally managed to find a solution!

With pymongo 3.X.X, we were able to connect to our documentDb instance by adding the parameter `tlsInsecure=true` to the original URI, which is passed to our `MongoClient`function.

For pymongo 4.X.X we had to add an extra parameter `directConnection=true` to make things work.

The `host` variable can be set to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and `username` and `password` can be encripted with urlib or not.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the certificate checking is validating the hostname you are using, so we can trick it by using the actual hostnames and mapping them in the hosts file to `127.0.0.1`.

Add each of the `docdb.XXXXXXX.region.docdb.amazonaws.com` to your calling system's [hosts file](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/edit-host-file-windows-10/), e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 docdb.XXXXXXX-1.region.docdb.amazonaws.com
127.0.0.1 docdb.XXXXXXX-2.region.docdb.amazonaws.com
127.0.0.1 docdb.XXXXXXX-3.region.docdb.amazonaws.com
```

Then change the host variable:

```
host=f"docdb.XXXXXXX-1.region.docdb.amazonaws.com:{port},docdb.XXXXXXX-2.region.docdb.amazonaws.com:{port},docdb.XXXXXXX-3.region.docdb.amazonaws.com:{port}"
```

And then change the URI to remove the port as it's now in the host variable:

```
dbUri = f'mongodb://{username}:{password}@{host}/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=./rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&retryWrites=false'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your solution makes a lot of sense (I was looking for something similar), but unfortunately it did not work. I added all the 3 addresses to `etc/hosts` and `private/etc/hosts` files, and I tested each address by pinging every alias individually which went fine (all the traffic is routed towards 127.0.0.1 which indicates that they are correctly configured, I think). By subsituting the host variable by the real db instances names, I get a python error saying that  the server is unreachable.

Comment: Have a play around with the connection string on the command line using mongo / mongosh attempting to connect. Once you have a working connection string the same string should work from pymongo

Answer (score 0):

Add &tlsAllowInvalidHostnames=true to the URI to skip the hostname check.